# DataAnnotations apply one of two RegularExpression based on selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I am using **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** for validating model state. My question is I want to apply following validation rule:

1.> EIN regular expression validation to field **"b"** if field **"a"** is true.

2.> SSN regular expression validation to field **"b"** if the field **"a"** is false.

Following is my model class:

```
Public class Applier
{

  public bool FieldOnWhichValidationDepends{get; set;}

  //If Above property is true then apply following regular expression for EIN
  [RegularExpression(@"^\d{9}|\d{2}-\d{7}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid format for EIN")]

  //If Above property is true then apply following regular expression for SSN
  [RegularExpression(@"^\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid format for SSN")]

  public string FieldToBeValidated {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: Conditional Validation is not built in ASP.NET MVC, see [foolproof](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=foolproof) validation for this.

Comment: This kind of validation can be validate using the CustomValidator. It is easy to handle more than one condition or regular expression in the IsValid method.